# Compress Video files in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, image-compression, video-compression

I am improving the performance of my application.

I want to compress images and videos to minimum size without any quality loss i.e. **lossless compression**.

For images, i've used **imagemin** package. It works well with **png** format, but for **jpeg**, its very **inefficient**.

For videos, i can't find any way to minimize video size without scaling down the resolution and without any quality loss.

Comment: **imagemin-mozjpeg** has actually worked well for jpeg images. Now stuck with Video files.

Comment: Not sure if this can help, https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

Comment: @Krish, Did you find any solution? I am facing a similar issue. Please help me,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed a compression service in our work.
Using FFMPEG [nodejs ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg)
Its the most common lib, but you need to make sure to install ffmpeg on the machine.
I decreased around 60% off the videos.
for example from 20MB to 9MB.
Good luck, its not easy to understand and not so easy to implement.

Answer (score -7):

**Jimp** is very good for image compression and resizing [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)